# Tensorflow on gpu: tf cant find gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, tensorflow2.0

I tried everything but tensorflow cant see my gpu. ı gonna show all versions to i have, can anyone has idea about this?
1- my nvidia
[image]

2 Cuda :version

[image]

3. CuDNN version : cuDNN (7.6.5)
4. my tf version

[image: ![enter image description here]

I follow  all this steps from there : https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-gpu-support-on-ubuntu-20-04-f6f67745750a

After this steps i controlled tf ;

```
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
2020-12-30 10:41:50.035846: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2020-12-30 10:41:50.047043: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-12-30 10:41:50.080921: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-30 10:41:50.081141: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.665GHz coreCount: 34 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-12-30 10:41:50.081155: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2020-12-30 10:41:50.107337: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2020-12-30 10:41:50.107387: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2020-12-30 10:41:50.126300: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-12-30 10:41:50.132954: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-12-30 10:41:50.204340: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-12-30 10:41:50.212418: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2020-12-30 10:41:50.212534: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/cuda/include:/usr/lib/cuda/lib64:
2020-12-30 10:41:50.212543: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
>>> tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
`[]`

>>> tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()
true
>>> tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, 

min_cuda_compute_capability=None)
WARNING:tensorflow:From <stdin>:1: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2020-12-30 10:42:47.612041: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2020-12-30 10:42:47.612151: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-12-30 10:42:47.612381: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.665GHz coreCount: 34 deviceMemorySize: 7.79GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 417.29GiB/s
2020-12-30 10:42:47.612400: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2020-12-30 10:42:47.612421: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2020-12-30 10:42:47.612431: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2020-12-30 10:42:47.612441: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-12-30 10:42:47.612450: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-12-30 10:42:47.612459: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-12-30 10:42:47.612467: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2020-12-30 10:42:47.615079: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/cuda/include:/usr/lib/cuda/lib64:
2020-12-30 10:42:47.615090: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-12-30 10:42:47.725208: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-12-30 10:42:47.725230: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2020-12-30 10:42:47.725235: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N 
False
```

Comment: Please do not post errors and messages as images. They can't be searched for and will make it much harder for future visitors to find

Comment: Cuda dependencies are tricky so may be reading it wrong, but to me it looks like your tf version expects cudnn 8.x (libcudnn.so.8). You may want to take a look there.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson may be you are right but, if you rewiev a tutorial, every version are same... really diffucult problems. thanks your advice.

Comment: [They](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) are not all the same !

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan Thank you Mohan, i will try to change true versions.

Comment: This message is quite clear: "Could not load dynamic library 'libcudnn.so.8'", you need cuDNN 8 (not related to CUDA 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the table here for anyone who has the same question .

| Version | Python version | Compiler | Build tools | cuDNN | CUDA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tensorflow-2.4.0 | 3.6-3.8 | GCC 7.3.1 | Bazel 3.1.0 | 8.0 | 11.0 |
| tensorflow-2.3.0 | 3.5-3.8 | GCC 7.3.1 | Bazel 3.1.0 | 7.6 | 10.1 |
| tensorflow-2.2.0 | 3.5-3.8 | GCC 7.3.1 | Bazel 2.0.0 | 7.6 | 10.1 |
| tensorflow-2.1.0 | 2.7, 3.5-3.7 | GCC 7.3.1 | Bazel 0.27.1 | 7.6 | 10.1 |
| tensorflow-2.0.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.7 | GCC 7.3.1 | Bazel 0.26.1 | 7.4 | 10.0 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.15.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.7 | GCC 7.3.1 | Bazel 0.26.1 | 7.4 | 10.0 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.14.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.7 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.24.1 | 7.4 | 10.0 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.13.1 | 2.7, 3.3-3.7 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.19.2 | 7.4 | 10.0 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.12.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.15.0 | 7 | 9 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.11.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.15.0 | 7 | 9 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.10.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.15.0 | 7 | 9 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.9.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.11.0 | 7 | 9 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.8.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.10.0 | 7 | 9 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.7.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.9.0 | 7 | 9 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.6.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.9.0 | 7 | 9 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.5.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.8.0 | 7 | 9 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.4.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.5.4 | 6 | 8 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.3.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.4.5 | 6 | 8 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.2.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.4.5 | 5.1 | 8 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.1.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.4.2 | 5.1 | 8 |
| tensorflow_gpu-1.0.0 | 2.7, 3.3-3.6 | GCC 4.8 | Bazel 0.4.2 | 5.1 | 8 |

Comment: after downgrade tf = 2.2.0 its work! thank you

Comment: Is it possible to get an updated list for 2022? Or at least, how did you get this table, so that people in the future can find it out for themselves?

Comment: @ShepBryan this list can be found in [https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)